# How to deal with aggressive homeless when exploring urbex?

Tags: geocaching, urbex

It's a geocacher's nightmare, when you do a nice urbex cache, and then, when leaving, find the entrance blocked by angry homeless, that seem to live there and are not happy from unexpected visitor (which isn't surprising).

How to deal such situations, to avoid the confrontation, which could end poorly, or loosing your wallet, which also isn't a dream situation? Are there any tricks to lighten the atmosphere, for example offering cigarettes?

Comment: From context I thought you are speaking about a wild animal, after that I googled 'clochard'. Is this really happening regularly to you? Can't think of a useful 'answer' to this, try to be as normal as possible without being dis-respective nor submissive.

Comment: Fortunately, I haven't met aggressive ones, but I've heard of geocachers threatened by aggresive scrap-collectors (probably thinking they have to deal with rivals, or hidden police agents). Useful answer: how to talk with them to rescue the situation. Offering cigarettes is the option that comes into my mind, but I'm not sure how it practically works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the great outdoors. It is a question about social interaction.

Comment: The questions should be on topic because it's about issues with geocaching, which is on topic.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Your last comment fits perfectly on the [boat programming meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about). The basic idea behind this meme is that relating something to the topic of a stackexchange site does not automatically make the question on topic.

Comment: I've asked on meta, is geocaching on topic, or it should have a separate site. If geocaching is on topic, than the whole scope of geocaching should be on topic, if not, it needs a separate site (which doesn't make a lot of sense). Urbex questions cross-topic with survival (urban survival) and parkour. Creating a lot of separate sites wouldn' make much sense with such a large cross-topic area.

Comment: To discuss whether or not this is on-topic, see [this meta question](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/479/566).

Comment: Maybe I should change 'urbex' to the 'cave' and than it will be on-topic?

Comment: Allow me to recommend defining or replacing the word clochards - many North Americans make up portmanteau words that end in "ards" or "tards" to make them more insulting, like securitard for example. At first read that's what I thought you were doing. Using a word like "vagrant" or "street person" might make your question more understandable.